# c# UriKind.Relative changed to UriKind.Absolute

Tags: c#, uri, relative-path, absolute-path

I would like to ask what happens if you change UriKind Relative to UriKind Absolute and vice versa? I tried to research for the answer but I couldn't find any that answered by question

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can "change" a relative uri into an absolute uri by giving a base uri that includes the missing components; and you can "change" an absolute uri into a relative uri by omitting a few parts.  The changes are perhaps less interesting that the fact that these are just different components.

An absolute Uri is fully defined by itself.  It includes the protocol (`http://` or `file://` etc.) the host (`stackoverflow.com` or none), the path (`/some/file/here.txt`) and optional components like the `?query` or the `#fragment`.

A relative uri may omit the protocol (`//example.com/test.txt`), the protocol and the host (`/dir/file.txt`), or the protocol and host and the first few path components (`subdir/file.txt`).

It's also more common for relative Uri's to contain `..` or `.` path components, though absolute uri's can contain those too.